# Replacement for found = None?

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem with my shop program code. If the user enters a valid GTIN-8 number in my file (products.csv), the program goes through and works fine. However, if the user enters a valid GTIN-8 code that is not in the file, my code is not working.

I want it to print 'code is not found' and then repeat the program.
At the moment, it's just going to 'not found' then 'how many would you like to purchase'

I'm using found = None which I'm pretty sure is wrong but not sure what to change.

(See checkfile function)

```
def getproductcode():
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        code = input("Please enter the product code")
        valid = validatecode(code)
    return code

def validatecode(code):
    valid = False
    while True:
        if len(code) == 8:
            for i in code:
                try:
                    int(i)
                    valid = True
                except ValueError:
                    print("You have entered an invalid code type. Product codes are 8 numbers long. Please try again.")
                    return  False
            valid = checkvalidity(code)
            return valid
        else:
            print("You have entered an invalid code type. Product codes are 8 numbers long. Please try again.")
            return False

def checkvalidity(code):
        number = code
        total = int(number[0]) * 3 + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) * 3 + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) *3 + int(number[5]) + int(number[6]) * 3 + int(number[7])
        if total%10 == 0:
            check = 0
            print("Valid.")
            return True
        else:
            print("Invalid. Please try again.")
            return False
import csv

def checkfile(code):
    found = None # This seems redundant?
    with open('products.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for line in reader:
            print(line) # To see what you're getting 
            if code == line[0]:
                print("We found your product ", code)
                return line
        print(code, "is not found. Please try again")

def quantityFunction():
    valid = False
    while True:
        quantity = input("Please enter the amount of this item you would like to purchase: ")
        for i in quantity:
            try:
                int(i)
                #repeat()
                return int(quantity)
            except ValueError:
                print("We didn't recognise that number. Please try again.")
                return int(quantity)

def repeat():
    print("Would you like to add another product?")
    print("1. Yes")
    repeatchoice = input("2. No")
    if repeatchoice == '1':
        return True
    elif repeatchoice == '2':
        return False
    else:
        print("We didn't recognise your choice. Please try again")
        repeat()

import datetime       
def append(product, quantity):

    f = open("reciepts","a")
    #time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    #f.write(time)
    #for i in range(len(product)):
       #1 product 
     #   f.write(product[i])
    f.write(product)
    quantity = str(quantity)
    f.write(quantity)
    with open('products.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for line in f:
            print(line[1])

   # f.write(product)
    f.close


def reciept():
    print("Here is your reciept:")
    f = open("reciepts","r")
    print(f.read())
    #print("Here you are",f.readline())
    print("Thank you for shopping with Shoesmith's Home & Office Supplies Superstore. Please come again soon")
    print("Goodbye")

#rather than just print the file, read in each data to have decent formatting. i.e f.read data(1)



#main
f = open("reciepts","w")
f.write("")
f.close
repeatchoice = repeat()
repeatchoice == True
while repeatchoice == True:
    code = getproductcode()
    #print(code)
    product = checkfile(code)
    #print(product)
    quantity = quantityFunction()
    print(quantity)
    print(repeatchoice)
    addtoreciept = append(product, quantity)
    print(repeatchoice)
    repeatchoice = repeat()
    print(repeatchoice)
    #print(repeatchoice)
reciept()
#print(product, quantity)

'''with open('products.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(",")
            if code == data[0]:
                print("We found your product ",data)
                return data'''
```

My csv looks like this;

- 34512340  Plain Brackets  0.5
- 12395675  Yellow Pencil Sharpener 2
- 56756777  100mm Bolts 0.2
- 90673412  L-Shaped Brackets   1.2

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try using a debugger. There is many ways of controlling the flux of your application, what you are kind of using is a sequence but you need a state machine. What I suggest you to do is read about recursive methods, this methods allow you to call then in a desired sequence depending on a state.

Comment: Another suggestion is using an IDE like eclipse or pyCharm, it help a big lot with debugging and refactoring. There are a lot of unused vars in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the most efficient way, but it seems to be working...

I am now using   `if product is not None:` in several of my functions which stops the code from skipping into the quantityFunction.

Answer (score 0):

First, please attempt to reduce the amount of code that you post in a single block.  From your question it's clear you think the error is in the `checkfile` function - consider pasting just that function.

The `checkfile` function doesn't do anything if there's an invalid code except to print that the code is not found.  In particular, it doesn't return anything, which means it will return None.  Put whatever behavior you want after the print statement.

The statement `found = None` does seem to be pointless, unless `found` is used in a part of the code not pasted here.

Comment: Found is not part of the code elsewhere, the full code is listed.

Comment: I want the program to loop back to the start and run through my main program again in the case of an invalid code. What would you say I need to return based on what is in my code at the bottom title #main ?

Comment: Whatever I put after the print statement, the program just keeps taking me to the quantity step @jeremyweirich

Comment: To answer your second comment, there's nothing in `main` to handle if the returned value for `product` is `None`.


Since you're returning `None` as the value of `product` if the product code is valid and not in your database, a quick and dirty fix would be to do a check to see if `product is None`, and if it is, `continue`.


[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) are the flow control tools available for you.